# How to put this Android email send code in service?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-manifest

has anyone know how to put/move this email send code to the service??
here's the code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"myemail@hotmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
```

here'e my service code (Not Works and give me some "force close"):

```
@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sendEmail();
    }

    public void sendEmail()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"myemail@hotmail.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");

        try {
            getApplication().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(EmailService.this,ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(EmailService.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

please help for solving my problem.. thanks..

Comment: Why do u want to do it in a Service?

Comment: @user7777777777: because i want to sent email silent'ly via background.. i'm creating lockscreen application and need that code for sending a user's password via email to user's email when the user's forgot the password.. any idea? thanks..

Comment: Can you post the logcat message that u get when force close appears.?

Comment: how to copy a logcat messages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because i want to sent email silent'ly via background

That is not possible via `ACTION_SEND`. You will need to integrate your own SMTP library (there's an Android port of JavaMail available someplace) if you want to send email without user involvement.

> Not Works and give me some "force close"

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "Force Close".

Also, do not use `getApplication()`, as you do not need it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mark.. but in this case i don't want to use external library (javax mail library).. is that possible to make it mark??

Comment: @Michael Frans: You are welcome to write an SMTP client from scratch.

Comment: "You are welcome to write an SMTP client from scratch." >> i'm still not understand about this statement mark.. sorry, because i'm still newbie in Android developer world.. can you give me some example how to do that?? if not disturbing you.. Thanks mark..

Comment: @Michael Frans: Writing your own Java classes that implement the SMTP protocol has nothing to do with Android. Buy yourself a book on Java networking, buy yourself a book on the SMTP email protocol, and start writing. Now, anybody with a kilogram of sense would use JavaMail, since that is already written and debugged, saving you weeks or months of development time, but it is your decision.